# Using ftp command results name or service not known

Tags: command-line, ftp

I am connected to a server via an ssh tunnel.

I try to do the following on the server:

```
(uiserver):u75875246:~ > ftp ftp1011438-projects@176.18.47.219                
ftp: ftp1011438-projects@176.18.47.219: Name or service not knownftp>
```

Does somebody know what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ftp command does not support the @ syntax . Instead, there must be another way.

```
ftp 176.18.47.219
```

then enter your username and password.